# C++ Equivalent Windows of dl library

Tags: c++, dll, libdl

I created an app that encrypt decript using OpenSSL.

To compile/link it in g++ needed to include static libs:

```
g++ -o gssag agent_main.cpp libssl.a libcrypto.a -ldl -std=c++14
```

this "dl" library seems to be a library to load dinamic libraries that LINUX need.

I dont undersand why need them if using *.a static libraries. But without this ld library nothing works.

But In Windows using openssl and crypto *.libs g++ linkeditor also ask for dlopen functions.

What I use in Windows to substitute the linux dl library???

Comment: `-ldl` loads the [`libdl` library](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3LIB/libdl/) though I'm not sure that's what you're looking for here. The documentation implies it's been moved to `libc` which means this stub is no longer relevant.

Comment: If you're asking for the Windows equivalent, MSDN has you covered: [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get a windows openssl dll and use the LoadLibrary function instead of dlopen.

```
HINSTANCE hDllInstance = LoadLibrary(_T("MyDll.dll"));
if(!hDllInstance)
{ /* dll failed to load */ }
```

Comment: I am not using dlopen. The linkeditor advise that need dlopen function when I try to link OpenSSL and Crypto static libraries. Then I suppose this libraries need dlopen function. But in Windows which library give this functions???

Comment: `dlopen` does not exist on Windows. [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a distant equivalent, but [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) is *really different* on Windows & on Linux. Read [*Linkers & Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) to understand the details